# UI table have been broken

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG p-table for display list data. It work fine before, but currently, I start it again and UI have been broken.

Please check image for detail
[image: a busy cat]

This error only in Chrome (my ver: 73.0.3683.103 )

Libs: Angular 4, PrimeNg

Have you experience this case ?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: can you share minimal example with code that we can check - a stackblitz will be more helpful here

Comment: Hi @AkberIqbal, Code is popular, it write by primeNg and angular.
I have check, it work in previous chrome, and latest chrome (73.0.3683.103) is get this error.